# Loading really large RData Files in R

Tags: r, performance, save, load

I am trying to load a really large RData file with ~300 objects (mostly data frames and matrices) and a total size of ~47G.

It's really slow and takes about a day to load. Is there any faster alternative?

I know about saveRDS but saving each of the 300 objects separately is not an option. However I can perhaps save into 10 RData files. Might that be faster?

The Disk is standard 7200 rpm, so that's not a huge bottleneck, or even if it is, it can not be changed.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you create this file? If storage is not an issue you can try saving with `save(..., compress = FALSE)`. This will increase the size of the file on the disk but will speed up saving and loading considerably. Depending on what you are trying to do it may also be a good idea to use eg an sql database rather than RData files.

Comment: not sure why the "saving 300 objects separately" is not an option, but if it is due to the amount of manual input, you can try: `vget <- Vectorize(get,"x")`, `vsaveRDS <- Vectorize(saveRDS,c("object","file"))`, `vsaveRDS(object = vget(ls()),file = paste(ls(),".rds",sep = ""))`. That will also save the functions you newly defined, but you can quickly delete

Comment: @konvas Thanks! I will try saving it uncompressed. I created this file by preprocessing a large dataset.

Comment: @Chris Yeah, I could automate it but I guess there will be too many files to take care of. And also not sure if loading them separately will be any faster.

Comment: I have not tried this out, so I am leaving this as a comment. But I think the ``archivist`` package (https://cran.r-project.org/package=archivist) could help here. See: http://smarterpoland.pl/index.php/2014/09/lazy-load-with-archivist/